# How to access child component's value in other child component in angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

i have an angular 2 project setup, in which there is a parent component called 'app component' and in ap component there are 2 child component called 'child1 component' and 'child2 component' .

my project structure looks like :

```
app.component
   -- child1 component
   -- child2 component
```

Now my question is:  I have a button in 'child1 component' and there is a variable 'variableOfChild2Component' in 'child2 component'. Now When I click that button of 'child1 component's', the variable value of child2 component should change. How can I achieve this requirement in angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

For component interaction, resort to services, I am just going to use a quick name for the service, but use something meaningful for your use case.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private dataMessenger = new Subject<any>();

  getData(): Subject<any> {
    return this.dataMessenger;
  }

  setData(newData: any) {
    this.dataMessenger.next(newData);
  }
}
```

Now in your component 1 with the button

```
.
.
.
export class Component1 ... {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  buttonClick() {
    this.myService.setData("Pass anything you want here");
  }
}
```

Now in your component 2 class

```
.
.
.
export class Component2 ... {
  variableOfChild2Component: any;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getData()
                  .subscribe(data => {
                    // data argument contains whatever you pass to MyService.setData() 
                    // function inside your Component1 class when the button is clicked
                    this.variableOfChild2Component = data;
                  });
  }
}
```

You need to register `MyService` in your module, for example, the `AppModule`

```
@NgModule({
  .
  .
  .
  providers: [ ..., MyService, ... ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: But when i am refreshing the Component2, then its not going inside subscribe. I want when i refresh the component2, data should be there after subscribe.

Comment: Then you persist it somewhere and retrieve it when you think is appropriate, add that warrants a different question

Comment: What should be the solution for this??? Because i have tried to make a static property in another component and passed the data to it, but when i refresh the browser, that property goes undefined.